# Word boundaries with non-word characters

Tags: regex

With the regex matching expression
`\b.*#\b`
why are these two examples matched as below (highlighted):

`a #b #`c #

`a #b #c #`d

Specifically, how come the first string does not match contain everything up to the last #?

Since a word boundary (\b) is a zero width match that can match between a word character (\w) and a non-word character (\W) or between a word character and the start or end of the string, I am not sure how ending an expression with a non-word character would affect the match.

Comment: What are you actually trying to match?

Comment: My initial intention was to match words ending with # in a text.

For instance, abc# and cde# in abc# hij cde# fgh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your current regex:

```
\b.*#\b
```

And here is the first sample input:

```
a #b #c #
^^^^^^      <-- last word boundary is here
```

The first word boundary in fact occurs before the initial `a`.  Then, `.*` will greedily consume everything up until the *last* `#` which is followed by a word boundary.  As you quoted, a word boundary occurs between a word and non word character, or vice-versa.  The last time this happens is `#c`, because the final `#` (keeping in mind that `#` is *not* a word character) is not followed by a word character.

If you just want to grab all words which end in `#`, then just use this:

```
[^# ]+#
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I did not know about the "vice-versa" part of using \b, when a non-word character is followed by a word character.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

On the first string `a #b #c #`
there is not a word boundary  `a #b #c #` <-here and -> EOS

so `\b.*#\b` matches `a #b #`c # because
there is a word boundary between `a #b #`<- here and here -> c #

---

On the second one `a #b #c #d` it's more a matching issue
first and a word boundary second.
It has to match a word boundary following a  #,
so it finds it between `a #b #c #` <- here and here ->d

---

Word boundary's are tricky at first,
but if you use a phrase, you'll never be confused by them again.

Comment: Good luck to you !

Comment: Your comment was pretty helpful for my understanding. Regular expressions are powerful but just tricky to get right.

Answer (score -2):

\b Can **only match** letters, numbers, underline, Chinese characters.It is a pity that # is not in it.

Comment: `\b` doesn't match any character! It's a zero-length assertion that matches a word boundary.